# Just upgraded to 16.10 and have lost wireless conectivity, I tried this in terminal

Tags: wireless

```
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [1028:020c]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k
07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
0: dell-rbtn: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: yes
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
kat@kat-Inspiron-3542:~$
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: It looks OK. I see no problems.

Comment: In system settings > network the toggle switch to turn on the wifi will not work

Comment: What did you upgrade to 16.10? Probably the upgrade was not smooth. And why would you upgrade 16.04 with support till '21 to 16.10 with support ending this month?

Comment: Was using 14.04  upgraded to 1604  then 1610  .  mistake I am sure  dell inspiron 15

Comment: The wireless adapter is "hard blocked". You need to press a button on the laptop to enable it.

Answer (score 0):

I would blacklist dell-rbtn as this is a newer kernel module and it is supposed to allow the FN combo to clear a hard block but if the FN combo doesn't work

`echo "blacklist dell-rbtn" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/dell-rbtn.conf`

Reboot

Comment: This is about bluetooth. I don't think it is related.

Comment: Have a look at the [source code](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/next/linux-next.git/tree/drivers/platform/x86/dell-rbtn.c)

Comment: This is really weird. And I never met this problem before with this platform driver. Maybe there is a hardware switch.